# Jquery - Having problems with .prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If user clicks on button why form doesn't submit? I tried using `.prev().prev()` but it doesn't works.

**HTML**

```
 <form id="my_form" action"pr.php">
   <input type="text" name="cf"><span class="save_btn">Submit</span>
 </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".save_btn").click(function(){
            // Trim data
            var trm = $.trim($(this).prev().val());
            // Check length of data
            if(trm.length == 0){
                alert("Field can't be empty");
            } else{
                $(".save_btn").prev().prev().submit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: .parent() is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: - nevermind - deleted comments

Comment: @Cosx you are awesome dude! Thank you.  Make an answer so i can accept it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.parent()` This finds the element parent and in your case, the form element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use closest

```
$(this).closest('#my_form').submit();
```

Comment: That works same as .parent(). Thank u, i will use it in future :)